# Alias in bash_profile executes by itself

Tags: bash, macos, git-bash

I have set up an alias in ~/.bash_profile as follows:

`alias lcmt="git show $(git log --oneline | awk '{print $1;}' | head -n 1)"`

However, whenever I open a terminal window, I see:

`fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git`

I have been able to narrow it down to that particular alias because when I comment it out, there's no error message. Why does it evaluate by itself on OS X? Can I prevent it from doing so?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `$(...)` inside a double-quoted expression gets executed at the time of the assignment, the creation of the alias. You can avoid that by escaping the `$` of the `$(...)`. And you want to do the same thing for the `$1` inside the `awk` command:

```
alias lcmt="git show \$(git log --oneline | awk '{print \$1}' | head -n 1)"
```

Comment: Huh, thank you! Additional question, is this OS X specific? I could have swore I put very similar command into my Fedora bashrc at the office without escaping the ampersands.

Comment: Nope, this would be the same behavior in any Bash on any platform. Btw amperstand is `&`, dollar is `$` ;-)

Comment: Damn, two for two, someone is on fire tonight! :D Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Usually people put single-quotes around alias definitions to avoid problems like this. But in this case you also want single-quotes around the `awk` script, and quotes don't nest, so it gets messy. I'd recommend a function instead; see my answer.

Answer (score 4):

Shell functions are better than aliases in a number of ways, including that there's no quoting weirdness like there is with aliases. Defining a shell function to do this is easy:

```
lcmd() { git show $(git log --oneline | awk '{print $1;}' | head -n 1); }
```

I'd make two other recommendations, though: put double-quotes around the `$( )` expression, and have `awk` take care of stopping after the first line:

```
lcmd() { git show "$(git log --oneline | awk '{print $1; exit}')"; }
```